# xpath 2.0 selecting elements by attribute

Tags: xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I have been using the following xpath selection in xpath 1.0

```
<xsl:variable name="id"><xsl:value-of select="./@id" /></xsl:variable>
preceding::exm:messageFlow[@sourceRef = $id]/@targetRef
```

This worked very well and did exactly what I wanted.
However I started using XSLT 2.0 in combination with xPath 2.0 and this does not work anymore
(Using the Altova XML processor)
I get the following error:

> Kann nicht mit Ziel-Typ besetzt werden - Aktuelles Element ist 'sid-B3FD7EE5-043
>   3-4939-A69F-E74B30FDEB1C' vom Typ xs:untypedAtomic, Typ xs:QName erwartet - =

which translates roughly to:

> Cannot be set to target-type - Current element is 'sid-B3FD7EE5-043
>   3-4939-A69F-E74B30FDEB1C' of type xs:untypedAtomic, type xs:QName
>   expected -

Previously I had a similar problem with this selection:

```
following::exm:*[exm:incoming = $out] | preceding::exm:*[exm:incoming = $out]
```

Which again worked in xpath 1.0, but returned a similar error in xPath 2.0
After changing it to

```
following::exm:*[exm:incoming/text() = $out] | preceding::exm:*[exm:incoming/text() = $out]
```

It worked in xPath 2.0 as well. I did try doing something similar with the attributes, but it did not work

A small extract of the corresponding XML:

```
<messageFlow id="sid-80B618A4-E6BF-4438-AF5D-5111AD308FE6" name="" sourceRef="sid-B3FD7EE5-0433-4939-A69F-E74B30FDEB1C" targetRef="sid-6EB2DB76-CC19-48AD-A073-D37C7489F211"/>
<task completionQuantity="1" id="sid-B3FD7EE5-0433-4939-A69F-E74B30FDEB1C" isForCompensation="false" name="call service" startQuantity="1">
     <incoming>sid-2B2BA651-B5BA-4195-9B5B-E6855B1138F4</incoming>
     <incoming>sid-DA4B86E8-C3F2-497C-8C0D-218E95CE9FD1</incoming>
     <outgoing>sid-008948DE-BA59-4897-AC37-2C3AA63DCD82</outgoing>
</task>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder if you have a schema that declares the @id attribute as being of type QName?

With this variable declaration:

```
<xsl:variable name="id"><xsl:value-of select="./@id" /></xsl:variable>
```

you are creating a copy of the @id attribute in a new result tree fragment. This is quite unnecessary; your needs would almost certainly be better served by making the variable be simply a reference to the existing attribute, thus:

```
<xsl:variable name="id" select="@id" />
```

By making the copy, you are not only writing unnecessary code and incurring unnecessary run-time cost (building a new tree is an expensive operation), but you are also losing the type information. If my conjecture is correct that @id is of type xs:QName, then the variable $id after atomization will be of type xs:untypedAtomic, and comparing it to an xs:QName is likely to fail with a message similar to the one cited.

Comment: You were completely right about the problem being with a schema. After I removed all schema information from the source xml-file Alova did not throw anymore errors and everything worked as expected.

I tried keeping the schema and changing the variable as you described. However the error still persisted. Thank you for pointing out how I can improve the code, though.

Answer (score 1):

I can't reproduce the problem.

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="task">
    <xsl:variable name="id"><xsl:value-of select="./@id" /></xsl:variable>

    <xsl:variable name="vResult"
     select="preceding::messageFlow[@sourceRef = $id]/@targetRef"/>

    <xsl:value-of select="$vResult"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following document** (the provided fragment wrapped in a single top element and stripped off any undefined namespaces):

```
<t>
    <messageFlow id="sid-80B618A4-E6BF-4438-AF5D-5111AD308FE6"
    name="" sourceRef="sid-B3FD7EE5-0433-4939-A69F-E74B30FDEB1C"
    targetRef="sid-6EB2DB76-CC19-48AD-A073-D37C7489F211"/>
    <task completionQuantity="1" id="sid-B3FD7EE5-0433-4939-A69F-E74B30FDEB1C"
    isForCompensation="false" name="call service" startQuantity="1">
         <incoming>sid-2B2BA651-B5BA-4195-9B5B-E6855B1138F4</incoming>
         <incoming>sid-DA4B86E8-C3F2-497C-8C0D-218E95CE9FD1</incoming>
         <outgoing>sid-008948DE-BA59-4897-AC37-2C3AA63DCD82</outgoing>
    </task>
</t>
```

**when run with both Altova2011 and Saxon 9.1.07, produces the expected, correct result and no error is raised**:

```
sid-6EB2DB76-CC19-48AD-A073-D37C7489F211
```

Comment: damn. Thanks for your reply. It still does not work for me. I guess I will have to look over it some more